# java program repeats a text file instead of log out option

Tags: netbeans

I'm working on my project for a beginner java class.  The program is an authentication program for a zoo.  My program works fine except one thing.  After the user name and password are authenticated it is supposed to display a file that says "hello zoo keeper ...." and then ask the user to log out.  My issue is that after it displays the correct text file once it does not ask for the log out.  It repeats the text file 2 more times.

for example:

> Hello, Zookeeper!
>
> As zookeeper, you have access to all of the animals' information and
>   their daily monitoring logs. This allows you to track their feeding
>   habits, habitat conditions, and general welfare.
>
> Hello, Zookeeper!
>
> As zookeeper, you have access to all of the animals' information and
>   their daily monitoring logs. This allows you to track their feeding
>   habits, habitat conditions, and general welfare.
>
> Hello, Zookeeper!
>
> As zookeeper, you have access to all of the animals' information and
>   their daily monitoring logs. This allows you to track their feeding
>   habits, habitat conditions, and general welfare.
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 15 seconds)

I will put my code below and be thankful for any help that I can get.

```
     package AuthenticationSystem;

     //import necessary java tools
     import java.io.FileInputStream;
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.InputStreamReader;
     import java.security.MessageDigest;
     import java.util.Scanner;
     import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

     public class Authenticationsystem {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

    // fileinput reading txt iles
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    String txtline = "";

    //credentials elements
    final int NUM_ELEMENTS = 6;
    String[] storedUsername = new String[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    String[] role = new String[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    String[] hashPassword = new String[NUM_ELEMENTS];
    String username = "";
    String password = "";
    String hash = "";

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int user = 0;
    boolean verified = false;

    // user / pw array
    storedUsername[i] = "griffin.keyes";
    hashPassword[i] = "108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f";
    ++i;
    storedUsername[i] = "rosario.dawson";
    hashPassword[i] = "3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5";
    ++i;
    storedUsername[i] = "bernie.gorilla";
    hashPassword[i] = "a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b";
    ++i;
    storedUsername[i] = "donald.monkey";
    hashPassword[i] = "17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3";
    ++i;
    storedUsername[i] = "jerome.grizzlybear";
    hashPassword[i] = "3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900";
    ++i;
    storedUsername[i] = "bruce.grizzlybear";
    hashPassword[i] = "0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7";
    ++i;

    //dialog box entry
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "All entries are case sensitive.\n"
            + "Enter \"quit\" at any time to exit.", "Authentication System", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

    // enter username / password
    username = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter username: ", "Authentication System", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (username.equals("quit")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have chosen to exit. Goodbye.", "Authentication System", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
    password = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter password: ", "Authentication System", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    if (password.equals("quit")) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have chosen to exit. Goodbye.", "Authentication System", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }

    //exit after three checks
    for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

        // check user credentials 
        for (j = 0; j < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++j) {
            if (username.equals(storedUsername[j])) {
                String original = password;  // md5digest
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                md.update(original.getBytes());
                byte[] digest = md.digest();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (byte b : digest) {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
                }

                verified = true;
                user = j;
                hash = sb.toString();
            }
        }
        //if wrong entry, re-enter
        if (!hash.equals(hashPassword[user])) {
            verified = false;
            if (i < 2) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid user credentials. " + (2 - i)
                        + " attempt(s) remaining.", "Authentication System", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                username = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter username: ", "Authentication System",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (username.equals("quit")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have chosen to exit. Goodbye.", "Authentication System",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
                password = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter password: ", "Authentication System",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                if (password.equals("quit")) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have chosen to exit. Goodbye.", "Authentication System",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    break;
                }
            }
            //closes program if tries exceed 3
            if ((!verified) && (i == 2)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Could not verify credentials. Goodbye.", "Authentication System",
                        JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                break;
            }
        } // if user credentials work
        else {

            //get input from txt files
            // user if zookeeper
            if (username.equals(storedUsername[0]) || username.equals(storedUsername[3])) {
                fis = new FileInputStream("src\\AuthenticationSystem\\zookeeper.txt");
                isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while ((txtline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(txtline);

                }
            } //user is a veternarian
            else if (username.equals(storedUsername[2]) || username.equals(storedUsername[4])) {
                fis = new FileInputStream("src\\AuthenticationSystem\\veterinarian.txt");
                isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while ((txtline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(txtline);
                }
            } //user is an admin
            else {
                fis = new FileInputStream("src\\AuthenticationSystem\\admin.txt");
                isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while ((txtline = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(txtline);

                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            class logout {

                public void logout(String original) throws Exception {
                    int i = 0;
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    while (i == 0) {
                        System.out.println("To log out please press 1 then the enter key");
                        int result = input.nextInt();
                        if (result == 1) {
                            System.out.println("You have logged out.  Have a great day!");
                            i = 1;
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("You are still logged in.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would say, put this code into a for loop, and put all the user info into a two dimensional array.

```
// user / pw array


storedUsername[i] = "griffin.keyes";
hashPassword[i] = "108de81c31bf9c622f76876b74e9285f";
++i;
storedUsername[i] = "rosario.dawson";
hashPassword[i] = "3e34baa4ee2ff767af8c120a496742b5";
++i;
storedUsername[i] = "bernie.gorilla";
hashPassword[i] = "a584efafa8f9ea7fe5cf18442f32b07b";
++i;
storedUsername[i] = "donald.monkey";
hashPassword[i] = "17b1b7d8a706696ed220bc414f729ad3";
++i;
storedUsername[i] = "jerome.grizzlybear";
hashPassword[i] = "3adea92111e6307f8f2aae4721e77900";
++i;
storedUsername[i] = "bruce.grizzlybear";
hashPassword[i] = "0d107d09f5bbe40cade3de5c71e9e9b7";
++i;
```

You have a for loop down there, so you must know how to do this.

Secondly, your logic here seems funky:

```
//exit after three checks]
for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {

    // check user credentials 
    for (j = 0; j < NUM_ELEMENTS; ++j) {
        if (username.equals(storedUsername[j])) {
```

Etcetera.

This is surely where your problem lies, though to find out the specific line of code you are going to have to put break points in and step through the code, line by line - I know it is meticulous, but that is the name of the game being a developer. Debugging your own code is the most important skill you can have as a software engineer - and no one will do this for you.

Separate out those "security checks" into functions. Add console logging to show you what the app is doing if you don't want to debug line by line. The easier the code is to read, the more insight you will have into what is doing.

There are many ways to skin this cat, but your code must be neat and tidy for consumption by other developers. The "Quality" of code is often gauged by how quickly another developer can tell what is going on. If that measurement is applied to this code, it is rather poor indeed.

Comment: Thank you for your help so much especially for not giving me the answer , how else would I learn.  I had to find the right place for the break and now it on only prints one time but does not go to the log out option at the end of the program.  Any suggestions of where to start looking?